# Date calculation(Max_repitch_date) as per certain combination Pairs

Tags: sql, mysql

Team,

Below is the final table end result, i am looking for:
Repitch window  - 20
[image]

- Max_repitch_date is calculated by adding order_start_date plus 20.
  Calculation has to happen as per same combination and delivery_id
  pairs...(QWE 123, QWE 123)(QWE 345, QWE 345)(QWE 567 QWE 567) They
  are arranged as per least order_start_date.
- Row 1 and Row 2 will
  calculate max_repitch_date as per 1st pair(1 & 2) and populate
  max_repitch_date as (2022-10-27) by adding Repitch window(10) to it
  and UOM would stay as 'abc'
- Row 3 and Row 4 order_start_date is less than max_repitch_date of the prior combo(row 1 & row 2), so UOM should be updated to 'repitch'
  and max_repitch_date should not be not updated and should be the same as prior( row 1 & row 2)
- Row 5 and Row 6 order_start_date is greater than max_repitch_date of the prior combo ( row 3 & row 4), so the max_repitch_date should
  now be calculated by adding 20 days to row 5 and row
  6(order_start_date) as (2023-03-02)
- MaxRepitchDate_first_pass adds up that particular record order_start_date value to plus 20 and stores in it for all of its records

I am facing issue populating the max_repitch_date as per the expectation above....

- compositekey__c is the 'combination' in table.
- pps.Ord_Com_Time is the 'order_start_date' in table.

I used below query and data is wrongly populated....

```
CASE
    WHEN RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY pps.CompositeKey__c ORDER BY pps.DELIVERY_ID__C) > 1 AND 
        (pps.Ord_Com_Time < LAG(pps.MaxRepitchDate_first_pass) OVER (PARTITION BY pps.CompositeKey__c ORDER BY pps.DELIVERY_ID__C))
    THEN LAG(pps.MaxRepitchDate_first_pass) OVER (PARTITION BY pps.CompositeKey__c ORDER BY pps.DELIVERY_ID__C)
    ELSE  date_add('day', pps.ContractedRepitchWindow__c, pps.Ord_Com_Time)
END AS MaxRepitchDate_Final_Pass
```

Tried Rank, Dense_Rank, ROW_NUMBER and yet still facing the same issue:

It is populating as below:

```
Max_Repitch_date
2022-10-27
2022-10-27
2022-10-27
2022-11-12
2022-11-12
2023-03-02
```

Can someone please help me resolve this issue ? Thanks

Comment: Is `MaxRepitchDate_Final_Pass` the same as `Max_Repitch_Date` in your desired result?

Comment: What is the input data? Is it the same as the desired output without this column?

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Except for the table, i posted everything as text... I made some edits as well....Please have a look at it...Thanks....

Comment: If someone wants to try to code a solution, they won't be able to copy/paste the table to test it.

Comment: Your query has a bunch of column names that aren't in the sample table, like `CompositeKey__c` and `Ord_Com_Time`

Comment: *[Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)*, #5 and #3